# Boost linking error using msvc10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm trying to use Boost filesystem library, but I get the following link error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > &,class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@GDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@Z)
```

I link against filesystem and system.

Here are the compile and link commands (I am building for x86-64 bits using msvc10):

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG ...
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE ...
```

I built Boost filesystem and system with options `threading=multi link=static runtime-link=shared address-model=64`

Where is the error??

Thanks!

Massimo

Comment: Where in those settings do you specify the name of the library to link to?  Also, why don't you use the Visual Studio IDE to build your programs?

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm using QMake to build my project, because of company rules, so the name of the library I link to is specified in the qmake .pro file